# Django Rest Framework: Partial update (PATCH) and Foreign Keys

Tags: foreign-keys, django-rest-framework

I have two Django models (simplified):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    title = models.CharField()
```

For both models I use basic ModelSerializers:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Author
        fields = '__all__'

[similar code for BookSerializer]
```

Finally, I've implemented basic ModelViewSets:

```
class AuthorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Author.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.AuthorSerializer

[similar code for BookViewSet]
```

Now, I'm partially updating an existing book, leaving out 'author', as it should not change.

```
PATCH /api/v1/book/1/ 
JSON data: {'title': 'Lord of the Flies'}
```

I receive this error:

```
HTTP 400 Bad Request
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "author": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

I assume this has something to do with the fact that 'author' is a FK. I would however expect DRF to handle this by keeping the relation of the Book object intact and just updating the title.

I can't find anything about this in the docs or elsewhere on the web. I must be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

"author" is a required field and you didn't provide it in the update.

Either use the PATCH HTTP verb to bypass that constraint or set the author as `required=False`.

Comment: Then you may have something in your code or that you didn't pasted that prevents this to happen. I can't remember I've seen this while I was using patch.

Comment: You're right. As it turns out, there was a bug in a view mixin I had written.